# Text size of TextView for multiple android screens (mdpi, hpdi, xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi)?

Tags: android, textview

I am making an Android app. There is a rotatable `ImageView` in the middle of the screen with two `TextView`s (in bold) above and two `TextView`s below. It shows different on different screens.

Comment: Post your XML layouts

Comment: Can you show the layout or screenshot?

Comment: What do you mean by different are they displaced w.r.t the image or are you facing font size issues?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure in your XML layout you define the `TextSize` attribute in `dp`. Since it is density-independent-pixel, it won't be affected by different screen sizes.

From [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html):

> When specifying dimensions, always use either dp or sp units. A dp is a density-independent pixel that corresponds to the physical size of a pixel at 160 dpi. An sp is the same base unit, but is scaled by the user's preferred text size (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes).
>   When you specify spacing between two views, use dp.